# ¿Objetos que se muevan en Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

me gustaría hacer un cuadrado que se mueva en Unity, pero no se como hacerlo, busco y no lo encuentro, me podrían explicar como?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deberías echarle un ojo al método [translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) de tu componente transform.

Puedes acceder a este desde el update de tu script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Move the object forward along its z axis 1 unit/second.
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

        // Move the object upward in world space 1 unit/second.
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] colocar solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, edita tu respuesta y agrega lo relevante aqui

Comment: Es que la pregunta es bastante general....

Comment: estoy de acuerdo contigo, pero entonces debiste esperar por que las preguntas deben mostrar un mínimo de avance o investigación por parte del OP